# How to integrate Views with apache solr search?

Tags: views, search

In my site I am implementing zip code based search, for that I created one view of user profile and add one expose filter to it which is exposing result on postal zip code entered by user. Now I am thinking that exposed filter integrate with Apache solr.

Help me out for which module I have to use for it and how I configure it?

List of modules I have used in my project:

1. [addressfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield)
2. [geofield](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield)
3. [geocoder](https://www.drupal.org/project/geocoder)
4. [geophp](https://www.drupal.org/project/geophp)
5. [apachesolr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr)
6. [facetapi](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi)
7. [profile2](http://www.drupal.org/project/profile2)

Answer (score 4):

The module you want is the aptly named [Apache Solr Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views) which will allow you to construct views from the SOLR index. Configuration is pretty simple. It's kind of a drop-in module. You'll choose to create an "Apache SOLR view". From the project page:

> Create a view from admin/structure/views/add and choose Apachesolr search. All of the fields indexed in solr should be available as views fields/filters/sort. Configure the view as needed and save it

Hope that helps you. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you webkenny for your response and efforts! I am going to implement it.

Comment: You're welcome. If this did help don't forget to mark the question as answered. :)